# Yii Framework: Create a link with multiple parameters CHTML::link

Tags: yii

I would like to link to a different controller, passing in multiple parameters.

Comment: How is this an objectionable question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action',
                                     'param1'=>'value1',
                                     'param2'=>'value2',
                                     'param3'=>'value3')); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',
                       Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action',array(
                                                         'param1'=>'value1',
                                                         'param2'=>'value2',
                                                         'param3'=>'value3')); ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail to explain what advantages the createUrl method provides in this case?

Comment: There are no advantages in this case, the link will be parsed the same way.